# How to fetch two list A & B with values and compare?

Tags: java, list, selenium, loops, testing

I have 2 list, where as list1 has 5 values and list2 has 2 values as below,

| List1 | List2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | - |
| B | - |
| C | 000123 |
| D | - |
| E | 000876 |

I need to fetch both list and check which list1 value and list2 value
And I'm looking for output as below

A has -

B has -

C has 000123

D has -

E has 000876

Can someone help on this?
Tried below screenshot of code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMd4o.png)

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/673707

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your lists are same length and in list2 empty values are null.

```
    List<String> result =  new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        if(list2.get(i) == null){
            result.add(list1.get(i)+" has");
        }else{
            result.add(list1.get(i)+" has "+ list2.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(" - ",result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have considered that list1 and list2 will be of same size.

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("-", "-", "000123", "-", "000876");

    Map<String, String> newList = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        newList.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
    }

    newList.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " has " + value));
    
    OutPut: 
    A has -
    B has -
    C has 000123
    D has -
    E has 000876
```

Comment: list 1 & list 2 values are fetched by xpath, so how do i use xpath here